# Liquibase Database Migrations, Managing over time

Tags: database-migration, liquibase

We've been using Liquibase for our database migrations, which runs off the Migrations.xml file. This references all of our migrations so it looks something to the effect of:

```
<include file="ABC.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
<include file="DEF.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
<include file="HIJ.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
...
```

However, over time, this has grown immensely long.  Looking to refactor this has anyone solved this issue? What options are available to essentially condense all these going forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single answer, what works best depends on your environment, process, and why you want to trim them down.

Generally, I recommend just letting your changelog grow because existing steps are the ones you have tested, deployed, and know are correct. Changing them introduces risk which is always good to avoid. Keeping your changelog unchanged also allows you to continue to bootstrap new dev/QA databases the same way older instances were.

While there is some performance penalty to having a large changelog, Liquibase tries to keep it to a minimum and is primarily just parsing the changelog file and then reading from the DATABASECHANGELOG table which should scale well. Since `liquibase update` is usually ran infrequently, even if it takes a couple seconds to run it's often not a big deal.

All that being said, there are times it makes sense clear out your changelog. The best way to do that depends on what the problem you are trying to resolve is.

The easiest approach is usually to just remove the include references to your oldest changelog files. If you know that all your databases have the changesSets in ABC.xml and DEF.xml already applied you can just remove the references to them from your master changelog and everthing will be fine. Liquibase doesn't care if there are "unknown" changeSets in the DATABASECHANGELOG table. If you want to continue boostrapping dev and QA environments with ABC.xml and DEF.xml, you can create a second legacy" master changelog.xml which include them and either run both changelogs when needed or make sure the legacy changelog contains both the old and new changelogs.

If you do not want to completely remove changeLog references, you can manually modify the existing changeSets. Often times there are just a few changes that can make a big difference in update performance. For example, if an index was created and then dropped you can skip the cost of the create by removing the drop and create changeSets. Again, liquibase doesn't care for databases that already ran the changeSets and will not see them for new ones. If you have some databases that may still have the index and you want it removed, you can use an indexExists precondition on the drop changeSet after you delete the create changeset.

Precondition checks can be expensive as well, especially depending on the database vendor. Sometimes removing now-unneeded precondition checks can improve performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

So far this has not been an issue for us. Yes, you do end up with a lot of includes but so far I simply did not care. I would strongly suggest not to delete any old changeset or making changes to them. Try to keep everything reproduceable as-is.

Maybe it helps to group changesets by the version of your application. With that I mean that in your migrations.xml file include the files for each of version of your application which include your "real" changesets. That way you could also easily figure out which changeset belongs to which version of your application.